# PySide/PyQt Is it possible to get the string of an anchor in QTextBrowser

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, href, pyside, qtextbrowser

In the following code is there anyway for python to tell what the 'word' in the middle of the href tags was when receiving the anchorClicked signal?

```
word = '<a href>' + '<span style="background-color:#C0C0C0">' + word + '</span>' +'</a>'
```

I tried with the sender() method, but the sender is QTextBrowser, not the string, so that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the html, put the word in the href attribute:

```
 html = '<a href="%s"><span>%s</span></a>' % (word, word)
```

(NB: you may need to html-escape the words in case they include the characters <, >, &, or ").

You can then extract the word from the QUrl sent by anchorClicked:

```
 word = url.toString()
```

Alternatively, you could set the href to a key that can be used to look up the word data in a dict.

Comment: The site is telling me not to write thank yous, but seriously, this saves me a much harder alternative.